# How to run multipul modules in same file in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-aws-modules

I using `https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate` to generate certificate using terraform and aws.

How to run multipul domains in the same file in terraform? (not subdomain)

I try this but I have error `Error: Duplicate module call`:

```
module "acm_request_certificate" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "example.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}

module "acm_request_certificate" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "otherexample.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}
```

I looking for solution like:

```
const domains = ["example.com", "otherexample.com"]

foreach(domain of domains) {
 module "acm_request_certificate" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = domain
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you are using the same name for both modules.
They should be different, e.g.:

```
module "acm_request_certificate_example" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "otherexample.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}

module "acm_request_certificate_other_example" {
  source                            = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-acm-request-certificate.git?ref=master"
  domain_name                       = "otherexample.com"
  process_domain_validation_options = true
  ttl                               = "300"
}
```

Also, in terraform 0.13 you can use foreach for modules.

```
# my_buckets.tf
module "bucket" {
  for_each = toset(["assets", "media"])
  source   = "./publish_bucket"
  name     = "${each.key}_bucket"
}
```

See the details in the [release notes](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/website/docs/configuration/modules.html.md#multiple-instances-of-a-module).